# Check the status of a OSGI bundle in adobe CQ5

Tags: curl, aem

I am trying to check the status of all the bundles in OSGI console,which ones are in active or installed state.is there any curl command for that or some other way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The Felix Webconsole has an [Restful API](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-web-console/web-console-restful-api.html). you can use it to obtain the status of all your bundles:

```
curl  http://admin:admin@localhost:4502/system/console/bundles.json
```

Comment: If you're sick of using curl there is a nice wrapping tool that gonna provide you the list in a nice readable form: https://github.com/Cognifide/CQ-Unix-Toolkit/blob/master/cqosgi

Comment: @Mathew while i am using this tool i am getting an error "./cqapi: No such file or directory". what actual parameters do i need to rovide to use this tool?

Comment: Please consider cqapi a required library that makes cqosgi tool working.  See https://github.com/Cognifide/CQ-Unix-Toolkit/blob/master/README.md installation notes. For you it should be enough to paste the prerequisite to the same directory.